# How do I connect to my sql instance with node.js

Tags: node.js, sql-server

As the title says, I am trying to connect to my MSSQL instance using node.js. I have used many different versions of the code I have found on stack exchange, reddit, and tutorials from other sites. Nothing has seemed to work though. Whenever I use the wrong server I get a different error, but when I use this server I get an ETIMEOUT error.

The specific error is:
`Database connection failed: ConnectionError: Failed to connect to localhost\SQLEXPRESS in 15000ms`

This is some of the code I have tried. Every time I get the same error. I have been able to connect to the server and access the database using SSMS.

```
const express = require('express');
const sql = require("mssql");
const app = express();

/*-------------------add details of sqlConfig-----------------*/

const config = {
  user: "tester",
  password: "test",
  server: "localhost\\SQLEXPRESS",
  database: "TrainingSimulator",
};

/******************************************************************/
app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        await sql.connect(config);
        res.send("DB Connected");
    } catch(err)
    {
        res.send(err);
    }
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`service is running on:: [${port}]`);
});
```

I have also used:

```
const express = require('express');
const mssql = require('mssql');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();
const port = 3000; // or any port you prefer

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

// Database configuration
const dbConfig = {
  server: 'localhost\\SQLEXPRESS',
  database: 'TrainingSimulator',
  user: 'tester',
  password: 'test',
};

// Connect to the database
mssql.connect(dbConfig, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error('Database connection failed:', err);
  } else {
    console.log('Connected to the database');
  }
});

// Define API endpoints to interact with the database

// Start your server
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

Comment: Are you sure you have a named instance called `SQLEXPRESS` and that it is running? Where have you verified these things? Have you considered not catching the error and just letting it crash? You might get more details that way than with the friendly version of the error that sometimes masks important details.

Comment: On SSMS I can connect to `SQLEXPRESS` so I'm fairly certain that is correct. If I don't, how do I check that? I did not know that about the catching the errors thing. I will try that.

Comment: The extra info I got was `err = new ConnectionError(err)`

Comment: Unlike SSMS which can also use the Named Pipes and Shared Memory client-side drivers, the `mssql` package only uses the TCP/IP client protocol and so requires that the TCP/IP Server Protocol is enabled on the instance. Have you checked this in the SQL Server (version) Configuration Manager tool? If you make any changes here don't forget to restart both the SQL Server instance and the SQL Browser service as well.

Comment: Just tried it. Turns out that TCP/IP was disabled so I enabled it and restarted the instance.  I am still getting the same error however. Additionally, SQL Server Browser was stopped when I went to check on it

Comment: Okay wait nevermind that fixed it!

Comment: Answers go on the answers, not the question. I've rolled back your edit. If you want to post the answer, do so in the answer selection below. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had to go to SQL Server Configuration Manager, and from there enable the tcp/ip service. I also had to go to my windows services manager and changed sql server browser and sql server agent from disabled to enabled

Answer (score 0):

You can try using mysql2 package instead of mysql there are some Authorization constraints in mysql package I was facing the same issue. I fixed it by using mysql2 instead of mysql. commands you can use **npm uninstall mysql** and **npm i mysql2** and then import it.

Answer (score 0):

according to your "server: "localhost\SQLEXPRESS" line, I think you use an MS SQL server. Please try mssql dependency,

```
npm i mssql
```

this is the Microsoft SQL Server client for Node.js